# I Cannot bind a to date in pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Did someone know my problem? I have an Oracle database and I used pdo. I cant fetch data because there is a problem in binding the date column. Here is my code.

```
private function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if (count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                if (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $param) !== FALSE) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x,TO_DATE($param,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')); //THE PROBLEM IS HERE.<--
                }else{
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                }
                    $x++;
                    }
                }
                if ($this->_query->execute()) {
                    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                    $this->_error = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: TO_DATE should be part of your query, or use datetime to format it first.

Comment: ok i will try it.

Comment: from the upvote someone must be getting around to answering, hold tight.

Comment: If your mysql date field is a simple regular date field then a date formatted as Y-m-d G:i:s would work perfectly well without needing a TO_DATE? I'm pretty sure you can just bind a '2018-04-27' value and it work ok.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Oracle 'client' date format with NLS_DATE_FORMAT (valid formats are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A)) and then convert the date in PHP to the same format.  You would simply bind this string to the SQL statement without using any special processing.

In your code this would appear to be:

```
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d G:i:s', $param) !== FALSE) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                }
```

There are various ways to set NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  If you set it as an environment variable, you also need to set NLS_LANG.  Alternatively you can run an ALTER statement after connecting.  See the globalization chapter of [Underground PHP & Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) for details on setting the environment.